# Increasing display time in virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, android

I am using **android** in **windows 7** via **virtualbox**. Whenever my android screen blackens it is too tough for me to wake it up. I am turning it off to get away from the issue. Increasing the display time would be a good choice for me I thought. Then I tried **Machine** menu **> Settings** option **> Display** section. But I could find nothing there to change the display time. Help me reach out of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your guest OS, you need to extend the android screen timeout.  **Settings** option **> Display** section **> Remote Display** tab **> Authentication Timeout** text field.  Set this to a really long time and it should stop the screensaver from kicking in.

I've just been searching and the problem appears to not be with virtualbox but with the guest OS trying to initiate a screensaver